# I am making a game like Crossy Roads on Unity, the problem is, why the player fly away

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Basically, when the player hit an obstacle going up, the game generates a lane, its ok, the problem is: if he hit the obstacle 3 times, go to the side and jump up without hitting an obstacle, the player will jump 4 lanes instead of 1...

I tried to destroy the next lane when the player hit an obstacle and tried to cancel the movement, but its sens to crash or bug the game.

```cs
internal void SpawnNewStrip()     
{
    int stripsPrefabCount = poolOfStripsPrefabs.Length;
    int randomNumber = Random.Range (0, stripsPrefabCount);

    GameObject item = poolOfStripsPrefabs [randomNumber] as GameObject;

    Transform itemChildTransform = item.transform.GetChild(0) as Transform;
    Transform itemChildOfChildTranform = itemChildTransform.GetChild (0) as Transform;

    float itemWidth = itemChildOfChildTranform.gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer> ().bounds.size.x;

    GameObject lastStrip = strips [strips.Count - 1] as GameObject;

    GameObject newStrip = Instantiate (item, lastStrip.transform.position, lastStrip.transform.rotation) as GameObject;
    newStrip.transform.position = new Vector3 (newStrip.transform.position.x -  itemWidth, newStrip.transform.position.y, newStrip.transform.position.z);
        strips.Add (newStrip);
}

internal void JumpUp()
{
    if(gameIsPlaying == false)
            return;

    stripsCurrentIndex += 1;

    if (stripsCurrentIndex > indexOfTheHighestRoadStrip) 
    {
        Score += 1;
        scoreText.text = "Score: " + Score.ToString();
        indexOfTheHighestRoadStrip = stripsCurrentIndex;
        Debug.Log("new  score: " + indexOfTheHighestRoadStrip.ToString());
    }

    GameObject nextStrip = strips [stripsCurrentIndex] as GameObject;

    JumpTargetLocation = new Vector3 (nextStrip.transform.position.x - jumpOffsetX, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
    midWayPointX = JumpTargetLocation.x + ((this.transform.position.x - JumpTargetLocation.x) / 2);

    mesh.transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3 (0, 180, 0);

    SpawnNewStrip();

    float distanceX = this.transform.position.x - JumpTargetLocation.x;
    BoundaryLeft.transform.position -= new Vector3 (distanceX, 0, 0);
    BoundaryRight.transform.position -= new Vector3 (distanceX, 0, 0);
}


internal void JumpDown()
{
    if(gameIsPlaying == false)
        return;

    stripsCurrentIndex -= 1;

    if (stripsCurrentIndex < 0) 
    {
        stripsCurrentIndex = 0;
        return;
    }

    GameObject previousStrip = strips [stripsCurrentIndex] as GameObject;

    JumpTargetLocation = new Vector3 (previousStrip.transform.position.x - jumpOffsetX, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
    midWayPointX = JumpTargetLocation.x - ((JumpTargetLocation.x - this.transform.position.x) / 2);

    mesh.transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3 (0, 0, 0);

    float distanceX = JumpTargetLocation.x - this.transform.position.x;
    BoundaryLeft.transform.position += new Vector3 (distanceX, 0, 0);
    BoundaryRight.transform.position += new Vector3 (distanceX, 0, 0);
}
```

Just want the player to jump normally after hitting an obstacle.

Comment: Unfortunately that's a big block of code and you're unlikely to get much help.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, specifically this part:  
Help others reproduce the problem
… But don't just copy in your entire program! …  it likely includes a lot of irrelevant details that readers will need to ignore when trying to reproduce the problem. Here are some guidelines:
Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem. For help with this, read How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: @MatthewWetmore its looks better now? I hope so, I am new on the site and still learning, thanks for the advice.

Comment: You as well should study the [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So when jumping you increment stripsCurrentIndex with one. This however isn't decremented if you hit an obstacle. Meaning that if you are at a stripCurrentIndex = 0 and jump into an obstacle three times, it will set stripCurrentIndex = 3. Even though your position haven't changed. Then when you jump to the side and jump up you retrieve the strip from stripCurrentIndex = 4. Thus you will jump four spaces.

So you will have to either decrement the index when hitting an obstacle, like so.

```
if (isJumpingUp)
{
    offsetUpDown = 2.5f;
    stripCurrentIndex -= 1;
}

else if (isJumpingDown)
{
    offsetUpDown = -2.5f;
    stripsCurrentIndex += 1;
}
```

Alternately refactor your code so that the index is incremented only after you've actually reached the position. In a "Set target" - "Do actual movement" - "Increment index" fashion.

Comment: I see, in my code i using true and false so set the position, but now i think mine is a little complex... so i should use reset command in case the player jumps up...

Comment: Ah. I am changing my answer to fit the new information.

Comment: Thank you very much, i was losing my mind trying to figure it out.